# Does def- win over lambda-functions?

Tags: python, function, lambda

Since lambda functions have their limitations, it might be better to stick with the def functions. Even if lambda functions are a nifty way to write very short functions, isn't it easier to still use def functions as you are simply more used to it?

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as a "lambda function". Lambda expressions and `def` statements both define objects of type `function`. Use lambda expressions to define functions which you don't need to explicitly assign to a name (for example, for passing directly to a function call or to use a value in a `dict`). Use `def` statements for any function intended to be bound to a name. This means no code like

```
# bad style
foo = lambda x: x + 3
```

but rather

```
# good
def foo(x):
    return x + 3
```

The limitation of a lambda expression is that its body must be a single expression (whose value is returned). Any function whose body cannot be expressed as a single `return` statement necessarily must be defined with a `def` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is your line of thoughts here, but in the [Style Guide for Python Code PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) you read:

> Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier:

```
# Correct:
def f(x): return 2*x

# Wrong:
f = lambda x: 2*x
```

---

However, the difference goes beyond style here.
For example, with `lambda`, your callable does not get the name you bind it to in `__name__`:

```
def f(x): return x ** 2

g = lambda x: x ** 2

print(f.__name__)
# f
print(g.__name__)
# <lambda>
```

---

However, there is no good or bad in absolute terms. `lambda` serves a specific purpose, that is to create on-the-fly unnamed callables.

One such example in common use is sorting some object using a particular sorting function, e.g.:

```
l = list(range(-10, 10))

print(sorted(l, key=lambda x: abs(x - 5)))
# [5, 4, 6, 3, 7, 2, 8, 1, 9, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10]
```

It would be a bit cumbersome to write this as:

```
def f(x):
    return abs(x - 5)

sorted(l, key=f)
```

if `f` is not going to be used ever again.

Comment: The value of the `__name__` attribute has little to do with the function itself. It's a side effect of the `def` statement, and can be overridden as desired. `g.__name__ = 'f'` is perfectly legal. Code that relies on any particular value probably isn't very robust.

Comment: Sure. I just wanted to point out that the two snippets are *not* identical.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of examples show lambdas as

```
some_fctn = lambda x: x + 1
```

but really this is a silly thing to do. Write an anonymous function... then name it. You should just use def. I personally dislike using lambda this way and agree that you should use def instead.

But when a function is used as a parameter in another call and the task you want done fits in a single expression, then they start to make sense. Now the logic is near the point where it is used, not in some function you had to define outside of the current function.

```
new_list = sorted(['10', '2', '-30'], key=lambda x: abs(int(x)))
```

Comment: There are better examples of where `lambda` is useful, since this would be better written as `sorted(['10', '2', '30'], key=int)`.

Comment: @chepner - whatever. Toy examples are exactly that.